# Can't save image properly in Redis using the redis gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, redis, binary-data

I'm trying to save an image to Redis, which will be fetched and uploaded later in a Resque task to our image server.

An ImageHandle class will fetch an image for us. For now, I'm only concerned with getting an image in and out of Redis.

```
class ImageHandle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :uploaded, :image
  after_save :save_image

  def image_data
    $redis.get(redis_key)
  end

  def image=(value)
    @image = value
  end

  private

  def redis_key
    @redis_key ||= "image_handle:#{id}:image"
  end

  def save_image
    $redis.set(redis_key, @image.read)
  end
end
```

Where $redis is set in an initializer:

```
$redis = Redis.new
```

And this is my test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ImageHandleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

  setup do
    clear_redis
  end

  test 'saves an image' do    
    image = fixture_file_upload('screaming-eagle.jpg', 'image/jpg')
    # You can only read from a file fixture once
    same_image = fixture_file_upload('screaming-eagle.jpg', 'image/jpg')

    image_handle = ImageHandle.create(image: image)

    expected = same_image.read
    actual   = image_handle.image_data

    puts "length of expected: #{expected.length}"
    puts "length of actual:   #{actual.length}"

    assert_equal expected, actual
  end
end
```

And the results are:

```
length of expected: 81500
length of actual:   78524
F 

Finished tests in 0.270385s, 3.6984 tests/s, 3.6984 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_saves_an_image:23
```

I have no idea what's going on.

When I tried setting ("b" * 81500) and then getting it, I got it back at the expected length of 81500.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

redis-rb converts strings to default external encoding defined by `Encoding::default_external` which usually is UTF-8. See https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/commit/61fa1f884a643cd7dea8e0e56498860594058a39

You can encode your binary data as Base64 before storing them and decode from Base64 after retrieving:

```
class ImageHandle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :uploaded, :image
  after_save :save_image

  def image_data
    Base64.decode $redis.get(redis_key)
  end

  def image=(value)
    @image = value
  end

  private

  def redis_key
    @redis_key ||= "image_handle:#{id}:image"
  end

  def save_image
    $redis.set redis_key, Base64.encode(@image.read)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can covert string to ASCII-8BIT without losing data. Update this method:

```
def image_data
  $redis.get(redis_key).force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
end
```

It's faster and simpler than Base64.